# Python socket file server

Tags: python, sockets

There are many questions on stackoverflow discussing the client server model for sending and receiving files with python.

My question is a little different in that I want to create a python 'server socket', which listens on some port and then pushes a file to whoeever connects to that port.

I'm using the code below, however when I connect to the socket I do not receive the file.

```
s = socket.socket()        
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 2048))
f = open('/tmp/test','rb')
s.listen(5)           
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connection from ', addr
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
       print "Sending"
       s.send(l)
       l = f.read(1024)
    f.close()
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    c.close()
```

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?

Comment: try with `c.send` instead of `s.send`, but there are a few other little things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four problems here.

```
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 2048))
```

`gethostname()` returns the name of your machine, not an address you can bind to. If you want to bind to all interfaces, just like `s.bind(('', 2048))`.

```
s.send(l)
```

You're trying to send on the listener socket, not the connected client socket. Use `c.send(l)`. You make the same mistake later by calling `s.shutdown` instead of `c.shutdown`; you need it to fix it there, too.

```
s.send(l)
```

You're using `send` instead of `sendall`, and not checking the return value. You'll usually get away with this when your buffers are this small, but why accept "usually"?

```
f.close()
```

Since you only `open` the file once, before accepting the first connection, and then you `close` it for each connection, the second client is just going to cause an exception as you try to read from a closed file. Either move the `open` into the loop, or replace the `f.close()` with `f.seek(0)`.

Comment: I don't understand your first point (gethostname). Please explain. I have tried this piece of code and it works as a charm: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm

Comment: @Pynchia: Well, it will work in _many_ cases, but it's not guaranteed to work. If you have multiple NICs, if your LAN's DNS server doesn't know your machine's name, etc. And it doesn't do anything necessary even when it _does_ work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send on the server socket `s`, while you need to do that on the newly accepted client socket `c`.

**`Listening`** socket (`s` here) can only accept new connections. By definition it does not have the other end to exchange data with.